# Dynamically generated MS Word document from C# using HTML & CSS does not display header in word 2003

Tags: c#, html, ms-word

I am trying to generate an MS Word Doc using HTML and CSS from C# as in [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/Wordyna.aspx).

When I try to display an html styled header in the word doc, the document gets corrupted and does not open at all in word 2003. In some cases, the document opens, but the header is scattered all over the place, pushing the content downwards. However, the same document is fine on Word versions >= 2007.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? and what is the solution?

Comment: Personally, I had very good experiences with a completely other way of solving this task: I'm using [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx) (a commercial library) to generate my Word documents. Maybe this is also an option for you?

Comment: Thanks Uwe, but thats not an option for me. too expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use alternative like:

- http://b2xtranslator.sourceforge.net/
- http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j
- http://www.opendocument4all.com/download/OpenOffice.net.pdf

Optionally, try something like this:

```
        Dim Lic As New Aspose.Words.License
        Lic.SetLicense(Application.StartupPath & "\Aspose.Words.lic")

        Dim doc As New Aspose.Words.Document()
        Dim docBuilder As New Aspose.Words.DocumentBuilder(doc)
        docBuilder.InsertParagraph()
        docBuilder.MoveToHeaderFooter(HeaderFooterType.HeaderPrimary)
        docBuilder.Write("Hello World")
        docBuilder.MoveToSection(0)
        Dim f As Aspose.Words.Font = docBuilder.Font
        f.HighlightColor = Color.Yellow
        f.Size = 16
        f.Name = "Courier New"
        docBuilder.Write("hola")

        doc.Save("C:\HeaderTest.doc")
```